# Several IF statements with Indentation error

Tags: pyqgis, if-statement, indentationerror

I wrote a very long "if statement" script but something doesn't work. It returns several Indentation errors but I cannot understand where...could be something else?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import processing
#define layer
layer_sezcens=QgsVectorLayer(r'C:\Users\federica\Desktop\POLIMI\DOTTORATO\GIS MAPPING\Maggiolina_map\sezcens2.shx',"sezcens2","ogr")
#add new field
layer_sezcens.startEditing()
field_mainAge=layer_sezcens.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("MainAge",QVariant.Int)])
layer_sezcens.commitChanges()
#modify new field
layer_sezcens.startEditing()
field_mainAge=layer_sezcens.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('MainAge')
field_minDiffer=layer_sezcens.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('MinDiffer')
field_FlatsClass= layer_sezcens.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('maxFlatsC')
print field_mainAge,field_minDiffer,field_FlatsClass
for feat in layer_sezcens.getFeatures():
        if feat['E3']==NULL:
        expr_mainAge=0
    else:
        if feat('MinDiffer')>0: 
            if feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E8']:
                expr_mainAge=1
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E9']:
                expr_mainAge=2
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E10']:
                expr_mainAge=3
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E11']:
                expr_mainAge=4
            elif feat['MinScarto']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E12']:
                expr_mainAge=5
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E13']:
                expr_mainAge=6
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E14']:
                expr_mainAge=7
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E15']:
                expr_mainAge=8
            elif feat['MinDiffer']==feat['MaxFlatsC']-feat['E16']:
                expr_mainAge=9
        elif feat('MinDiffer')=0: 
            list_mainAge=[feat['E8'],feat['E9'],feat['E10'],feat['E11'],feat['E12'],feat['E13'],feat['E14'],feat['E15'],feat['E16']]
            max_AgeList=max(list_mainAge)
            if feat['E8']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge= 1
            elif feat['E9']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=2
            elif feat['E10']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=3
            elif feat['E11']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=4
            elif feat['E12']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=5
            elif feat['E13']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=6
            elif feat['E14']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=7
            elif feat['E15']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=8
            elif feat['E16']=max_AgeList:
                expr_mainAge=9
    print expr_mainAge
    layer_sezcens.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), field_mainAge, expr_mainAge)
layer_sezcens.commitChanges()
```

Comment: There are 8 space before the if when it should be only 4

Comment: @underdark thanks but which if clause do yu refer?

Comment: Providing the ***exact*** error  would be useful -- it would tell the exact line on which the error occurred.

Comment: @FedericaZ the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `if` is too indented and should be written that way:

```
for feat in layer_sezcens.getFeatures():
    if feat['E3']==NULL:
        expr_mainAge=0
```

I don't see other errors.